# ogr2ogr - "Unable to open datasource" error while converting shp to mif in code. Works fine when running command in console

Tags: gdal, shapefile, convert, ogr2ogr, mapinfo

I'm tyring to convert a shapefile to MapInfo using ogr2ogr. (C#/.NET 6)

I get the following error when running the code below: `Unable to open datasource [directory path]\file.mif`.

However, If I open cmd.exe in the ogr2ogr directory and copy/paste the argument, it executes and the shapefile is converted to .mif/.mid, as I would expect it to.

command line argument = `ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" -overwrite -dsco FORMAT=MIF "[directory path]\Polygon.mif" "[directory path]\Polygon.shp"`

**Code:**

```
var ogr2ogrPath = "[directory path]\\ogr2ogr.exe"

ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
  FileName = ogr2ogrPath,
  CreateNoWindow = true,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  RedirectStandardError = true,
  Arguments = $"ogr2ogr -f \"MapInfo File\" -overwrite -dsco FORMAT=MIF \"[directory path]\file.mif\" \"[directory path]\file.shp\"",
};

var streamOutput = "";

using(var shellProcess = Process.Start(StartInfo)) {
  StreamReader readerStdOut = shellProcess.StandardError;

  while (readerStdOut.EndOfStream == false) {
    streamOutput += readerStdOut.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
  }

  shellProcess.WaitForExit();
  streamOutput += " - Finished " + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Possibly due to the backslashes in the file path, try replacing them with double backslashes, i.e. `C:\\example\\test.shp`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The paths already have serialized backslashes/ double backslashes, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution, for anyone experiencing the same issue:

```
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
  FileName = "cmd.exe",
  CreateNoWindow = true,
  UseShellExecute = false,
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  RedirectStandardError = true,
  WorkingDirectory = [Path to ogr2ogr directory],
  Arguments = $"ogr2ogr -f \"MapInfo File\" -overwrite -dsco FORMAT=MIF \"[directory path]\file.mif\" \"[directory path]\file.shp\"",
  Verb = "runas"
};

var streamOutput = "";

using(var shellProcess = Process.Start(StartInfo)) {
  StreamReader readerStdOut = shellProcess.StandardError;

  while (readerStdOut.EndOfStream == false) {
    streamOutput += readerStdOut.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
  }

  shellProcess.WaitForExit();
  streamOutput += " - Finished " + Environment.NewLine;
}
```